# Reuse kubernetes letsencrypt certificate

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, cert-manager

I have a kubernetes cluster and I've been experimenting so far with cert-manager and letsencrypt ssl certificates.

Everything goes fine, I have issued an SSL certificate and applied to the cluster and https connection is working excellent.

The problem I face is that I am experimenting with new things and it often leads me to delete the whole cluster and create a new fresh one, which on it's side makes me lose the SSL certificate and issue a new one, but there's a rate limit by 50 certificates per week per domain.

Is there a way I can reuse a certificate in a new k8s cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the secret locally (`kubectl get secret -o yaml` and then clean up unneeded fields) and then upload it to the new cluster (`kubectl apply`).